# How to set up gnucash to use different currency pair quotes?

Tags: gnucash, quotes

Some currency pairs like XAU-CHF are not available directly, is there any way to use a different currency instead of my locale?

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn't find an answer, I modified the Perl scripts in question to try and make a detour via EUR if necessary, see https://github.com/Gnucash/gnucash/pull/1487 and https://github.com/Gnucash/gnucash/pull/1488, in essence I added

```
# If quotes aren't directly available, try a detour via EUR
# TODO reverse direction as above, detour via USD etc...
unless (defined($price)) {
    my $eur_price_from = $quoter->currency($from_currency, "EUR");
    my $eur_price_to = $quoter->currency($to_currency, "EUR");
    if (defined($eur_price_from) and defined($eur_price_to)) {
        $price = $eur_price_from / $eur_price_to;
    }
}
# end
```